# Is there a way to add an SSL certificate to a domain which we don't have control over?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

something.us.qlikcloud.com has a SSL certificate, but the SSL certificate it has is invalid. However, something.us.qlikcloud.com is not hosted on a server we control. Is there a way to modify the SSL and use a valid one? I was told we could host on a server we control and then redirect it to something.us.qlikcloud.com, but I am not sure how it would solve the issue. It's just a redirection and shouldn't have any impact.

Comment: Do you control the DNS records for that domain?

Comment: I have a DNS record on Route 53 that redirects it to that address, but we don't have control over the content of that address.

Comment: Most SSL providers will allow you to add a TXT record to a given domain and validate it that way.

Comment: bi.something.com CNAME Simple - 
something.us.qlikcloud.com

I have this DNS record, but even if I can validate the SSL, how can I replace the faulty SSL certificate on something.us.qlickcloud.com?

Answer (score 3):

If you do neither control the host in question nor the DNS zone the host's records are in, there's no way to accomplish what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

If you have control over DNS then you can set up your own reverse proxy (`nginx`, `haproxy`, AWS ALB etc.) and use it to terminate TLS/SSL and pass all the traffic to the existing backend. Alternatively, you can even set up a CDN (Cloudflare, AWS CloudFront etc.) and point it to the existing server.

Answer (score 1):

Request the owners of that domain/service fix it.

Via support channels with them, explain the TLS error and  insist it work without error in a modern browser.

Sure, you can work around by setting up your own domain and proxying to them. But why should they not have functional https? It is a required security practice for a modern web site.